# in the free tire of Mongo Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

Accidentally, I dropped the database without having any backup, and I am using MongoDB Atlas. What can I do?

I tried to search for how I can retrieve the log file and restore data from it, but I could not find anything. I need help to retrieve the data as it is so important.

Comment: You contradict yourself. Either the data is not important or you have a backup. No backup, no mercy.

Answer (score 1):

The free tier [does not offer backups](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/backup/cloud-backup/overview/). So if you didn't make one yourself with `mongodump` or similar, there's isn't any.

> #### Feature Unavailable in Free-Tier Clusters
>
> This feature is not available for `M0` free clusters. To learn more about which features are unavailable, see [Atlas M0 (Free Cluster), M2, and M5 Limits.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#std-label-atlas-free-tier)

And wrt being able to use [Atlas logs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/mongodb-logs/) to restore, it's also not available:

> `M0` free clusters and `M2/M5` shared clusters do not provide downloadable logs.